# Uninstall software not listed in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

My question is, how is software not listed in Ubuntu Software Center uninstalled?

Comment: How you uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it.

Answer (score 0):

If it came from apt you can use

```
sudo apt remove {package-name} or sudo apt purge
```

If it came from a deb file outside of the repo's.

```
apt-get remove
```

works as well.

Answer (score 0):

- If you've installed software using installation scripts, that puts binaries, libraries, config files to different directories, than you should remove those files by your own looking into script and analyzing where and what it copied. Use `rm` command if no uninstall script present.
- If you've installed it using `make install`, then try to use `make uninstall` command in the same directory
- If you've installed software using other package systems, use them for uninstalling. For example: `sudo snap remove gimp`
- Before uninstalling read documentation to software you're trying to uninstall. Maybe there're uninstall steps described